# Applying Fourier transform to a gaussian

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, gaussian-integral

Let $$G_\beta(w) = e^{\beta w^2}$$

Now I get the process of applying a fourier transform (or inverse) to get a new  gaussian:

$$G_\beta(x) = G_\beta(0) e^{\frac{-x^2}{4\beta}}$$  but in doing the derivation the constant $G_\beta(0)$ never arose. I know how to calculate the constant, but where did it come from in the derivation?

edit: Fourier form used: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(w) e^{-iwx} dw$$

Comment: First, it would help to include your definition of the Fourier transform in your question. Second, $G_{\beta}(0)=e^{\beta\cdot 0^{2}}=1$.

Comment: I get that it is equal to 1, but when you derive it you get this expression:  $G_\beta(x) =  e^{\frac{-x^2}{4\beta}}$   so is what your saying is that since we can "assume" that a one exists in front of my expression that it doesn't hurt to write $ G_\beta(0) $ in front of my expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess $\beta>0
 $ to have $G_{\beta}\left(\omega\right)=e^{-\beta\omega^{2}}
 $ integrable. The fourier transform $\widehat{G_{\beta}}
 $ has the following property :$$-ix\widehat{G_{\beta}}\left(x\right)=\widehat{\frac{d}{d\omega}G_{\beta}}\left(x\right).
 $$ Computing the derivative and using the above property again yields to an ODE :$$-ix\widehat{G_{\beta}}\left(x\right)=\widehat{-2\beta\omega G_{\beta}}\left(x\right)=-2\beta\left(-i\frac{d}{dx}\right)\widehat{G_{\beta}}\left(x\right)=2i\beta\frac{d}{dx}\widehat{G_{\beta}}\left(x\right).
 $$ The general solution is then $\widehat{G_{\beta}}\left(x\right)=Ce^{-\frac{x^{2}}{4\beta}}$
  and $C$ is found by taking $x=0$ for example.Here, the constant appears in the solution of a Cauchy' problem for an ODE.

Comment: There's an error. The general solution should be $\widehat{G_{\beta}}\left(x\right)=Ce^{-\frac{x^{2}}{4\beta}}$ (with $4$ instead of $2$ in the exponent).

Comment: @md2perpe You're right, thank you very much!